# Canvas JS libraries that allow object manipulations?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm looking for alternative solutions to build something like 
http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/quantity/  what allow manipulations on the canvas objects such as rotating, moving and scaling. More importantly, they do have control points so it's easy for the users.

I'm really afraid to get into the wrong path at beginning, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us more about your requirements? What exactly are you building?

Comment: Hi, Simon, I'm trying to build a collaborate whiteboard web app.

Comment: Why can't you use fabric.js (the lib in your example)?